# See executing script's filename path in htop - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I want to see the current processes that are running now.
Let's say I run [www.example.com/script.php](http://www.example.com/script.php)

Then I want in [www.example.com/seescripts.php](http://www.example.com/seescripts.php) to see
processes running:

1. /path/to/process/script.php

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in SSH"?

Comment: @treuss inside of putty console

Comment: PuTTY is a terminal emulator, an SSH client and more. SSH is a protocol that allows you to connect to a remote system. After you connect from PuTTY via SSH, you usually work in a shell (e.g. Bash) that allows you to run commands; some commands may be able to show you what you want. The screenshot you posted shows `htop`. Do you want to see some path specifically in `htop` then? or in whatever command is good for this? What kind of script? PHP?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Helo Kamil, yes. It doesn't have to be specifically in htop. It's fine in php aswell. Actually I would prefer in PHP if possible. Let's say I run example.com/script.php then on the page example.com/seescripts.php to see the path to the script that is running in that moment. The moment script stops, then it dissapears from seescripts.php aswell. Thank you!

Comment: Clarify your question by [edit]ing it. Users won't read all the comments. Make the question contain all the information.

Comment: Keep in mind that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be end-of-life by April 2023, so you should upgrade to a newer release in the near future.